# White notification in Android when app closed or minimized

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I just implemented FCM push notifications in my Android app and I am getting a weird behaviour, as it seems to load the silhouette icon only when the app is opened, but when it is closed or minimized I get a white circle instead. I think it is showing me the ic_launcher icon instead of my ic_stat_white icon. I made my base icon in photoshop and used Android Asset Studio to get all the sizes ( https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html ) and I have tried all the solutions I could find or think of, putting an extra value in the push notification message ("icon":"ic_stat_white"), invalidating caches, and everything I could find in Stack Overflow, with no results.

In my Firebase Messaging Service class I have the following code to create the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                        .setContentTitle("App name")
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentText(message);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
// Sets an ID for the notification
int mNotificationId = 001;
// Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Builds the notification and issues it.
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

and the getNotificationIcon method:

```
private int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);        
    return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.ic_stat_white : R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
}
```

I feel like the app can't get access to the icon from outside of the app or something like that, and although I have added

```
import com.appname.R;
```

it does not seem to be used at all.

Anyone know what the issue could be here?

Cheers!

Comment: Please see my answer to the same question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616065/android-notification-icon-issue/44879510#44879510

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was happening even if I set the icon from the FCM admin panel, but after creating my own backend controller in PHP seems that I am not getting this behaviour in the app, although if I do not call the push notifications with my own system I still get a blank icon (???) .

```
$title = "App name";
$message = $_POST['pushmessage'];

$ch = curl_init("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
$header=array('Content-Type: application/json',
"Authorization: key=longAPIKEY...fromFCM");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{ \"notification\": {    \"title\": \"".$title."\",    \"text\": \"".$message."\" , \"icon\" : \"ic_stat_white\"  },    \"to\" : \"/topics/allDevices\"}");

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Cheers!

Comment: See my answer to the same question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616065/android-notification-icon-issue/44879510#44879510