# Android Push Notification, when app is closed I get a different style

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM for notification, where everything is working fine, but till app is open, once I kill(close) the app or in background, I get the Notification in default style, can anyone help me with setting this notification style when app is closed(or any other suggestion).
Kindly help me with this, **Thankyou in Advance**

Here is my Code

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


    String title = "";
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle() != null){
        title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    }

    String message = "";
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() != null){
        message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    }

    Log.e("notification","recieved");


    sendNotification(title, message);

}



private void sendNotification(String title, String message) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0/*Request code*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    int color=getResources().getColor(R.color.dot_dark_screen2);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.account_outline)
            .setColor(color)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notificationSound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0 /*ID of notification*/, notifiBuilder.build());
```

[image]

Comment: what is the version of this device operating system.

Comment: mine is android lollipop 5.1

Comment: Also can you share your Notification code part. At-least minimum code of your notification might be helpful for analyzing this case.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot, now i have updated my code as well.......

Comment: Obviously because one is showed by your method and second is showed from gms/firebase library which use different code to create notification

Comment: im sorry could you show me where?

Comment: Hi @RajivReddy 1) Update the version to 9.8.0, then check it. 2) go through this thread https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/4

Comment: @Rameshbabu  current version is 11.0.1 so I don't think he is using older than 10.0.0

Comment: no Difference @Rameshbabu

Comment: @RajivReddy this type of question already asked a year back.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616065/android-notification-icon-issue

Comment: Is this behavior occurring on diff devices?

Comment: Yes......................

Answer (score 2):

I already posted a long explanation here:
[Android notification icon issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616065/android-notification-icon-issue/44879510#44879510)

TL;DR:

Most likely your problem is the difference between **notification-messages** and **data-messages**.

Please read: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

> Use notification messages when you want FCM to handle displaying a
>   notification on your client app's behalf. Use data messages when you
>   want to process the messages on your client app.

Comment: is there any possibility where is can keep onMessageReceiver running when app in background or closed, from a background Service?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you clarify?
If what you want is to keep the app running in background (because you need to download a file, or you need to do something else) you need use a Service and call startService from onMessageReceived()

Comment: Yes, call startService with onMessageReceived(), so when i send Firebase message, the notification appears with set style. (not default system tray one)

Comment: ?? startService doesn't have anything to do with notification style. Please read my answer and comment again.